# Place a Dropdown and a Checkbox side by side in bootstrap horizontal form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I try to add a checkbox after all my `<select>` dropdowns but in the same row / line. I have a really hard time doing so, I tried quite some time now and I can't get it to work on my own. The CSS comes from Bootstrap 3.

Here is how my Code and Form looks like:

```
     <form role="form" id="newchar" name="newchar" method="POST" action="inc/insertchar.php">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
              <label for="charname">Charactername</label>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="maximal 16 Zeichen - bestehend aus Zahlen und Buchstaben">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </a>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="charname" id="charname" placeholder="Charactername" required="required" />
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
              <label for="c1">Circles:</label>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <select name="circle_1" id="c1" class="form-control circle-select">
                    <option value="">Circle 1</option>
                    <option value="class_1">Archer</option>
                    <option value="class_2">Cleric</option>
                    <option value="class_3">Swordsman</option>
                    <option value="class_4">Wizard</option>
                 </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <select name="circle_2" id="c2" class="form-control circle-select" disabled="disabled">
                    <option value="">select Circle 1 first</option>
                 </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <select name="circle_3" id="c3" class="form-control circle-select" disabled="disabled">
                    <option value="">select Circle 2 first</option>
                 </select>
              </div>
<!-- and more ... -->
```

Full Code and Preview: https://jsfiddle.net/hd7fzp95/

Comment: where is your checkbox in the code?

Comment: @RachelS I removed them again, because wherever I placed it - it appeared below the dropdowns or completely destroyed the layout. Most of the time it looked like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qztkrnee/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `form-inline` class on your form.

http://www.bootply.com/WpiddtxsOh

Comment: When I use `form-inline` then the whole form get's pressed in one line, like this: http://www.bootply.com/KuNtijMOWO That is not what I tried to accomplish, I just try to get 2 elements (one dropdown and one checkbox) in one line.

Comment: You have to add each "row" in a col-xs-12 or something simliar: http://www.bootply.com/JOEbTDroCi

Comment: Then the width of the dropdowns is either pretty small or they are dependend on the first `option` text width. Wich both is pretty ugly. But I actually did something completely different now, without even using checkboxes. Thanks for your effort though!